# How to insert multiple rows in mysql using procedures when we have array data to send in

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have set of codes where i need to insert multiple rows in `MySQL` using procedures

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","company");
$array_item = 'Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [user_name] => VANITHA
        [adddress] => 
        [mobile_no] => 8877665544
        
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
       [user_name] => VANITHA1
        [adddress] => rere
        [mobile_no] => 8877665544
       )
);

        
';
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"CALL addnew($array_item)");
```

procedures codes are as follows

```
 CREATE  PROCEDURE addnew(IN ArrayDemo VARCHAR(100))

    BEGIN  

    insert into geektable (user_name,adddress,mobile_no) 
                    values(user_name,adddress,mobile_no);  
 
    END
```

Comment: And what's you question about this? Anything not working so far?

Answer (score 0):

There is no array parameter in `MySQL`. What you need to do it to loop through the array in PHP and call the procedure for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can send multiple parameters, or you can create your own function to split the VARCHAR:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

Usage:

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR(string, delimiter, position)
```

Example:

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR('aa1|bb2|cc3|dd4', '|', 2) as second_item;
```

will return `bb2`

Comment: One could try to pass the JSON as a string to the routine and then parse the different rows/columns fron the string. While possible, the process would be error prone and far more complex than simply looping the array in PHP side and calling the procedure.

Comment: @slaakso for MySQL > 8 you can use JSON Datatype

Comment: That is correct. However, Rajesh's question did not have any JSON in it (based on the information provided).

Comment: You are right on that